# Update deeply nested Array using Nodejs in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update address based on _id for the nested array object in below document:

```
{
  "_id": "fb369348-341b-11e9-9e05-03b09392591c",
  "user": [
    {
      "_id": "fb369349-341b-11e9-9e05-03b09392591c",
      "name": "test1",
      "address": [
        {
          "_id": "fb369350-341b-11e9-9e05-03b09392591c",
          "loc1": "place1, chennai, India",
          "type": "home"
        },
        {
          "_id": "fb369351-341b-11e9-9e05-03b09392591c",
          "loc1": "palce2, chennai, India",
          "type": "work"
        }
      ]
    },
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

I am using below query in mongodb its working fine and the record is getting updated:

```
db.user_details.update(
    { "user.address._id": 'fb369350-341b-11e9-9e05-03b09392591c' },
    { $set: { 
            "user.$.address.$[i].loc1": "11111111111",
            "user.$.address.$[i].type": "fdfdfddfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf" 
            } 
    },
    { arrayFilters: [{ "i._id": 'fb369350-341b-11e9-9e05-03b09392591c'}] }
)
```

but when I am trying to use the above query in node js I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'castForQuery' of undefined

Can anyone help me to understand why I am getting a castForQuery error, _id is uuid and saved as string type?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. In my case everything was right but my mongoose version was not appropriate.

I salved my issue by updating the Mongoose version. Previously I was using `mongoose@5.0.15`. By the following command, I upgraded my mongoose version.

```
npm install mongoose@5.5.11
```

After that, it worked.